# How do I get back the packages I removed?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Someone asked me, on [an issue I'd reported on Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5574#issuecomment-349478465), to remove a couple of packages and test it without them. I'm sure the implicit request was for me to do it safely!

Anyway, I removed the packages (in this case, `libicu52` and `libssl1.0.0`), planning to get them back afterwards. It turns out both of these packages were dependencies of, respectively, `libpsl0` and `spotify-client`, which were also removed. As you might expect, reinstalling each did not go as planned:

```
$ sudo apt install libicu52
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libicu52 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libicu52' has no installation candidate
```

Same is true for `libssl1.0.0` and the depending package`libpsl0`.

If I try to install the depending package `spotify-client`, I am seeing the following:

```
$ sudo apt install spotify-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libavcodec54 but it is not installable or
                              libavcodec-extra-54 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libavformat54 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

You can see the results from the end of my `dpkg.log`:

```
2017-12-05 23:30:49 startup packages remove
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status installed libpsl0:amd64 0.5.1-1
2017-12-05 23:30:49 remove libpsl0:amd64 0.5.1-1 <none>
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status half-configured libpsl0:amd64 0.5.1-1
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status half-installed libpsl0:amd64 0.5.1-1
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status config-files libpsl0:amd64 0.5.1-1
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status config-files libpsl0:amd64 0.5.1-1
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status installed libicu52:amd64 52.1-8+deb8u5
2017-12-05 23:30:49 remove libicu52:amd64 52.1-8+deb8u5 <none>
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status half-configured libicu52:amd64 52.1-8+deb8u5
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status half-installed libicu52:amd64 52.1-8+deb8u5
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status config-files libicu52:amd64 52.1-8+deb8u5
2017-12-05 23:30:49 status config-files libicu52:amd64 52.1-8+deb8u5
2017-12-05 23:30:49 startup packages configure
2017-12-05 23:31:01 startup packages remove
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status installed spotify-client:amd64 1:1.0.64.407.g9bd02c2d-26
2017-12-05 23:31:01 remove spotify-client:amd64 1:1.0.64.407.g9bd02c2d-26 <none>
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status half-configured spotify-client:amd64 1:1.0.64.407.g9bd02c2d-26
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status half-installed spotify-client:amd64 1:1.0.64.407.g9bd02c2d-26
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status config-files spotify-client:amd64 1:1.0.64.407.g9bd02c2d-26
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status config-files spotify-client:amd64 1:1.0.64.407.g9bd02c2d-26
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status config-files spotify-client:amd64 1:1.0.64.407.g9bd02c2d-26
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status not-installed spotify-client:amd64 <none>
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status installed libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1t-1+deb8u7
2017-12-05 23:31:01 remove libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1t-1+deb8u7 <none>
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status half-configured libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1t-1+deb8u7
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status half-installed libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1t-1+deb8u7
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status config-files libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1t-1+deb8u7
2017-12-05 23:31:01 status config-files libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1t-1+deb8u7
2017-12-05 23:31:02 startup packages configure
```

Should I be worried? Should I try to get my packages back? How should I go about that?

Comment: Versions may have changed (and they are kind of hardcoded in the package name). Do a `apt-cache search libicu` and `apt-cache search libssl` to find the current ones and try installing these.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've done it, and I've also verified that these are installed via `apt list | grep libicu` and `apt list | grep libssl`. Should I remove and reinstall these packages?

Comment: Try just reinstalling `spotify-client` and `libpsl0`, they should then automatically bring the dependencies they need.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek There are problems. `libpsl0` is the same (`no installation candidate`) and as for `spotify-client`, please see my update to my answer.

Comment: Have you seen the message: `you have held broken packages`. Do an `apt-get --fix-broken install` before trying anything else.

Comment: Then do an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` before re-installing the needed packages.

Comment: @Arrow I actually did do that, oddly `apt-get --fix-broken install` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you do it as root after an apt-get update?

Comment: @Arrow Yep, sure did.

Comment: For the spotify one, at least, it looks like some changes a while back to my sources may have something to do with it. Check out this issue: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web-Player/Spotify-Kali-Linux-not-working/td-p/1470187

Comment: Maybe the problem in that case is Stretch not allowing you to install an old version of `libssl1.0.0` anymore, so it is `spotify-client` being out of date. Which is fine! I don't need that package.